# ClickOnce Application stopped working when I added www record, AzureWebsite, Godaddy

Tags: c#, .net, azure, dns, clickonce

I have 45 windows client computers running my C# Desktop App, every change I make I upload it with ClickOnce.

It's a Webapp at Azure (xyz.azurewebsites.net). My Installation Folder URL (App -> Settings -> Publish) has that address. And the domain is bought from GoDaddy. In the Azure dashboard, I added a Custom Domain (www.xyz.azurewebsites.net), and my ClickOnce deployments are currently saying: "The application is improperly formatted". It seems, from what I've researched, that is not a certificate signing problem nor a manifest problem. Did my original URL (still alive) stopped working only because I added www to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested with custom domain (www.mydomain.com), everything works fine like the following screenshot:
[image]

Does your web app works when the domain like mydomain.com (without www)? If it only not work with the domain www.mydomain.com. I would suggest you use dig web interface to check the DNS route. For how to map a custom domain name to an Azure app, please refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/).

Comment: Thank you!! the website digwebinterface (referred in the article) answered my questions :)